# Checking these two subsets of $\mathbb Q$ for closedness and compactness in $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ separately.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness, real-numbers

$1.\left\{q\in \mathbb Q:1\le q^2\lt 3\right\}$

$1.\left\{q\in \mathbb Q:1\le q^2\le 3\right\}$

If the sets were simply $$1.\{r\in \mathbb R:1\le r^2\lt3 \}$$and$$2.\{r\in \mathbb R:1\le r^2\le3\}$$ we could say the **first one is semi closed** and **the second one is compact**. But the sets we happen to have here are  $$1.\{r\in \mathbb R:1\le r^2\lt3 \}\cap\mathbb Q\\\text{and} \\ 2.\{r\in \mathbb R:1\le r^2\le3\}\cap \mathbb Q$$

So I think we need to consider two different cases::

> **Case $1.$**

When our entire space is $\mathbb Q$ with subspace topology induced from $\mathbb R.$

In this case, both of the sets are  **closed** and compact. Replacing $\lt$ by the $\le$ does not change anything in the given context.

We can rewrite the sets as follows-

$1.\mathcal A=\left\{q\in \mathbb Q:1\le q\lt \sqrt3\right\}$

$1.\mathcal B=\left\{q\in \mathbb Q:1\le q\le \sqrt3\right\}$

Now,$\sqrt3\notin\mathbb Q$

So,$\mathcal A^c=\left((-\infty,1)\bigcup (\sqrt3,\infty)\right)\cap \mathbb Q=\mathcal B^c$ which is open in the subspace topology that $\mathbb Q$ inherites from $\mathbb R$.And hence $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are closed and bounded as well $\implies$ compact.

> **Case $2$:**

When our entire space is $\mathbb R$ and we consider the sets $\mathcal A=\left\{q\in \mathbb Q:1\le q\lt \sqrt3\right\}$ and $\mathcal B=\left\{q\in \mathbb Q:1\le q\le \sqrt3\right\}$ above are considered as merely subsets of $\mathbb R$ to be judged then both sets are bounded but **neither is  even closed** because neither contains the set of their limit points,i.e. the sets $\mathcal A \cap \mathbb Q^c$ for $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B\cap\mathbb Q^c$ of $\mathcal B.$

So,in both the cases, the signs $\le$ and $\lt$  do not make any difference in the results.

But when the case is not specified, I'm simply to assume that our space is $\mathbb R$ and the **Case $2$** holds. Thoughts please. Thank You.

Comment: Does closed and bounded imply compact?  In Q?

Comment: If the first 1 is not compact in R, can it be compact in Q?  If a set is open in R will it's restriction to Q be open?  So if 1) has an open subcover with no finite subcover in R, does restricting it to Q cause the cover to no longer be open?  Does it cause a finite subcover to come into existence?

Comment: @fleablood: I'm editing a bit. Please note.

Comment: @fleablood : Now, I guess the set $\mathcal A^c$ is open since in subspace $S\subset X$, we say $W\subset S$ is open if $W=U\cap S$ where $U$ is open in $X$. right?

Comment: You are on the right track, but I think you setting setting yourself up for false analogies of declaring sets are open because they are in what look like open intervals. As it turns out that is correct but... you have to verify it.  The only real mistake you are making is that the Heine Borel theorem isn't true for Q.  Example: (1, sqrt 3) is not closed in R so it is not compact and so there is an open cover with no finite subcover.  But the set *is* closed in Q.  But the same open cover still has no finite subcover.  So not compact.

Comment: A little mistake : $\mathscr A=\left\{q\in\mathbb Q:-\sqrt3<q\le1\text{ or }1\le q<\sqrt3\right\}$.